# How to update data in List with specific by another field in the entity using Room in Kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I have a list (the data from room) with some item and I want to update data in that item. For example, I have a list like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 0  // the default value it's 0 / null but I showed in the app with 0 not null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": null  // the default value it's 0 / null but I showed in the app with 0 not null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 0  // the default value it's 0 / null but I showed in the app with 0 not null
    }
]
```

Then I want to update `value` in the list with specific by `mptId`.

I already created Dao like this:

```
@Query("UPDATE table_data SET value=:value WHERE mptId=:mptId")
fun testUpdate(value: Int?, mptId: Int?)
```

And then, on my ViewModel like this:

```
val list = _currentSource.value as List<SourceDanaInvestasi>
viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
    try {
        for (i in list) {
            repository.updateTest(i.value, mptId.get()) // i.value that I want update, mptId that where clause
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Timber.e("Error update investment fund : ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

For example, in the app, I will update the `value` in the list like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 10 // I edited from apps, the value from 0 to 10
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 10 // I edited from apps, the value from 0 to 10
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 20 // I edited from apps, the value from 0 to 20
    }
]
```

But, when I show the list after edited, the result is like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 20  // the value replaced by the last value
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 20  // the value replaced by the last value
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 20  // the value replaced by the last value
    }
]
```

The `value` is always replaced with last `value` from the apps. As you can see, I edited from app with `10, 10, 20` and then the last value is `20`, So all `value` in the list replaced by `20` too. Why it's happened?

And, when I edited the list from the app like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 0  // the value still 0 or I didn,t edited from the app
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 0  // the value still 0 or I didn,t edited from the app
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "mptId": 12,
        "value": 20  // I only edited this value from 0 to 20 in the app
    }
]
```

When I have edited like that, all item list didn't updated, I already debug it and the data it's updated but didn't save to the room, it's mean like all list must edited so it's can save to the room. Why it happened too?

So my question is, what the best practice to update the data from a list using room with specific field in the entity like `mptId`?

Fyi, `id` it's primary key with auto-generated, `mptId` it's a foreign key and the `value` it's what I want to edited from the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mptId is the same throughout the list items. Hence all the records with mptId=12 are updated. So you can see the error where the last value is reflected among all the list items. You need to update the records in the database based on 'id' rather than 'mptId'.

Edit:

What I understand from your description is this: 
You have a list with different records where all the mptId values are 12. And when you try to update different records with 10,10,20. After edit, you get the updated list as 20,20,20. Am I right?

If so: you query is

```
@Query("UPDATE table_data SET value=:value WHERE mptId=:mptId")
```

Intially list contains:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 0  
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": null  
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 0  
}
]
```

And then you update the list as:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 10 // the value from 0 to 10
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 10 //  the value from 0 to 10
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 20 // the value from 0 to 20
}
```

]

And then you call this:

```
    for (i in list) {
        repository.updateTest(i.value, mptId.get())        }
```

The loop literates 3 times.

Iteration 1:
Here you are trying to update all records with mptId=12 with value 10

Result: Room updated:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 10
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 10 
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 10 
}
```

Iteration 2:
Here you are trying to update all records with mptId=12 with value 10

Result: Room updated:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 10 
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 10 
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 10 
}
```

Iteration 3:
Here you are trying to update all records with mptId=12 with value 20

Result: Room updated:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 20 
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 20 
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "mptId": 12,
    "value": 20 
}
```

This is the final result which you are seeing.

**Solution**:

Can you update your query as:

```
  @Query("UPDATE table_data SET value=:value WHERE mptId=:mptId and id = :id
  ")
```

For loop as:

```
for (i in list) {
        repository.updateTest(i.value, mptId.get(),id.get())        }
```

This will work if the id in the list and id in the database table are same.

Comment: Fyi, Why I use `mptId` then `id` it's because of this table relation with another table. So when I edit another table based on `PK`, but in this table, I edit based on `FK` (mptId). `PK` on other tables is `FK` on this table.

Comment: And yes, I need to be updated all records with mptId=12 (with the same mptId). But the problem is, all `value` it's always same record, does not vary according to input by an app. I mean, in the app I edited all `value` with `mptId=12` from `0` to `10,10,20` and then the `value` is `20,20,20`. It's should be `10, 10, 20` right?

Comment: And also when I edited `value` from the app like this, `10,0,20` (0 it's mean I don't edit it). The `value` not edited, it's mean like all `value` must always be edited. So this is my problem too. And ya, you can read my question again about my problem.

Comment: Sorry for late, FYI, in the `SourceDanaInvestasi` model it's from API and didn't have `id` (primary key) because it's from API. And the example of my list, it's from another model (entity) with `id` is PK and autogereated. So the flow is like this. First, I open the page and get data from API, then I back to prev page with save all data from API (from `SourceDanaInvestasi`  to new model/entity) to room. Then I open that page again, but for now, get the data from the room (entity) not from API because prev already save it.

Comment: After that, I edited the `list` then open to the new page with `updated` data. And how to get `id` in the for loop from API (`SourceDanaInvestasi`) to match with `id` from entity as `PK` ? If see your answer, we need to set `id.get()` but how to get the `id` dynamically from entity? So the `query update` can know the `id` that I matched on the function for update the data in the room.

Comment: does the API give you only the edited records or all records of mptId=12?

Comment: And also does your model SourceDanaInvestasi have any unique field?

Comment: So, the API gives me a `list` with only one item or more. In that list, `users` who use the app can `edit` all items (`values`) in the list or only partially with `where clause` it's `mptId` because that is `PK` in other entity (parent) and `FK` on this table.

Comment: Yes, have, from API give a `lji_id` as String. `It's unique and will not be the same as other items and only applies to the same mptId`.

Comment: That's why I use `mptId` for `where clause`

Comment: Since lji_id will be common to the mptId with same value, it is not possible to use it. Yes I get what the intention of code is now. Since there is no direct way to handle the updation of single records, what I can think of is this: 1) example:  If you intend to update the records with mptId=12, it may be better to remove all records from the databse with mptId=12. And insert all the list items with mptId =12 after updating again. So this might help you.Since you will be removing the FK records, it will not harm the PK.

Comment: In order for it to not cause an overhead, try not to hit the database on single item edit  from user. You can do it when back press , until then the changes can be in temporary memory.

Comment: Already try to adding `lji_id` and `mptId` as `where clause` it's work. Thanks!